# Two synchronised clocks accelerated perpendicular to Earth's gravitational field

Tags: relativity

If I have two synchronized (at the station while waiting for me) clocks on a train, one at front and the other one at back, and I start to accelerate the train perpendicular to Earth's gravitational field then do those clocks go out-of-sync? Say, I accelerate at rate 0.1 m/s^2 till the speed equals 20 m/s and the distance between the clocks is 100 m.

Are those clocks out-of-sync when I travel comfortably after the acceleration?

**Edit**: Using gravitational time dilation for solving the problem sounds odd when I'm not accelerating along a gravitational field.

**Edit 2**: If I accelerated **perpendicularly** to a gravitational field I should have, according to the equivalence principle, experienced out-of-sync for my clocks. Does there exist any experimental evidence for the phenomenon? Theory isn't a proof.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which clock is the fastest inside an accelerating body?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112645/)

Comment: Hi Kimmo. In the duplicate I've suggested it's an accelerating rocket not an accelerating train, but the argument is the same.

Comment: @JohnRennie So it won't make any difference if I accelerate perpendicular to a gravitational field? Is there any experimental evidence about the phenomenon where the acceleration occurred perpendicular to a gravitational field? I mean using gravitational time dilation sounds a bit odd if I'm not accelerating along a gravitational field.

Comment: Correct. The fact that we can use the ideas of gravitational time dilation when describing the effect of acceleration is called the [equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle) and it is at the core of general relativity.