# Under what conditions is the time component of proper acceleration zero?

Tags: special-relativity

Given the magnitude of a proper acceleration, the derivative of proper velocity with respect to proper time, how do you determine what component is from the spatial vs temporal dimensions.  I am led to believe from wikipedia that the temporal component is zero, however do not understand why.  Is this always true?

Comment: Hi. Maybe you should start with understanding what a *derivative* actually means? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Rigorous_definition

Comment: Perhaps this might help.http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68108/why-proper-acceleration-is-du-dt-and-not-du-d-tau