About relativistic momentum and energy
So we differentiate displacement (from our frame of reference) with respect to proper time of the moving object $\dfrac{dx}{d\tau}$ to get to the momentum equation: $$p=\gamma mv$$
But when we derive the energy equation: $$E=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathrm{d}x$$
we use our time instead of the object's.
Why do we use our time to get the energy and the object's time to get the momentum? And, why do we differentiate displacement from my frame of reference with respect to the object's (proper) time to get the momentum? (Why don't we use the contracted displacement from the object's reference frame?)

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68108/123208

You simply got it wrong.
$$\tag1\begin{pmatrix}E/c\\\vec p\end  {pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\gamma mc\\\gamma m\vec v\end  {pmatrix}=mc\begin{pmatrix}\frac{c\,\mathrm dt}{c\,\mathrm d\tau}\\\frac{\mathrm d\vec x}{c\,\mathrm d\tau}\end  {pmatrix}$$
i.e. both quantities are defined using the proper time of the moving object in the denominator, and the numerators are all your coördinate functions.

Ok but why is the numerator my co-ordinate functions but denominator object's proper time

Why not? The energy and linear momentum of an object depends upon the frame at which you are measuring the object, and isn't inherent to the object itself. As such the coördinate functions are suitable for the numerator. In the denominator, the only time variable that everybody can agree to be the only thing that matters, is the proper time of the object. This way of doing things thus make physical and intuitive sense.

The coordinate functions together define a manifestly covariant vector. The proper time is manifestly covariant. So the result is also manifestly covariant

The theory of relativity is geometrical. The properties of a curve do not depend on how we parametrize it.

@naturallyinconsistent is correct. Additionally, proper time is the closest thing you'll come to "real objective actual time" because it's the only time that's Lorentz-invariant. It's special because it falls along the geodesic. It is unaccelerated.
BUT:
Every point of mass in the universe has in its watch pocket its very own private "right now." These clocks are completely independent and run at different rates.
If they run at the same rate for a while, it's temporary. They'll de-sync as soon as either of the two objects moves any amount in any direction.
That inviolate "right now" which only you own is proper time.
