# Differential equation for speed relate to the homogeneous cosmological background in FLRW metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, cosmology

How to derive DE for the speed (which relate to the homogeneous cosmological background) of the observer which moves with constant proper acceleration in spatially flat FLRW universe?

Comment: That speed would be the derivative of the proper distance, $\dot{D}$. To calculate $D$ for a cosmological relativistic rocket, see this post: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/73251/24142

Comment: @Pulsar . Thank you. But why the derivative of the proper distance refers to the peculiar speed?

Comment: @Pulsar : so for getting the differential equation I must differentiate $D$ twice?

Comment: @Pulsar : if I understood correctly,
$$
\mathbf s = a (t) \mathbf r , \quad \dot {\mathbf s} = \dot {a} \mathbf r + \mathbf v_{pec}, \quad \ddot {\mathbf s} = \ddot {a} \mathbf r + \dot {a}\dot {\mathbf r} + \ddot {\mathbf v}_{pec} = \mathbf g_{prop}?
$$
Does it matter that it is not covariant?

Comment: The derivative of the proper distance will give you the change in total distance, i.e. the contribution of the expansion of the universe + the local proper acceleration. Be careful, though: the proper acceleration is constant in a local inertial frame, it is NOT equal to the second derivative of the cosmic proper distance (the name 'proper' has two different meanings here; it's an unfortunate name clash between a quantity in special relativity and a quantity in cosmology). Also, I assumed that the initial velocity is parallel to the acceleration, so the motion is 1-dimensional.

Comment: So, one gets $\dot{D} = \dot{a}D_c + a\dot{D_c} = \dot{a}D_c + v$, and if necessary, $\ddot{D} = \ddot{a}D_c + \dot{a}v + \dot{v}$, where $D_c(t)$ and $v(t)$ are defined in the link.

Comment: @Pulsar : thank you once more. So I can't rewrite $\ddot D$ in term of some function which involves constant proper acceleration?

Comment: You can, but it involves the derivative of $v(t)$ (see the equation in my previous comment). Note that $v(t)$ is a function of the proper acceleration $g$ (see the link).

Comment: @Pulsar : I need to rewrite the left side of the equation (in terms of the proper acceleration) which you wrote down in the comment. So you write that it is possible? But how exactly to get the relation between $\ddot {D}$ and the proper acceleration $g$? Excuse me, I can't understand your statement fully.

Comment: I figured out how to solve this issue.

Comment: It would be good if you (or somebody else?) then could write an answer, so that the question doesn't become an orphan.